# Present a view modally from a TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to present one of the views in tab bar modally. 
Similar to what Instagram does when you tap the + button.

Sample code:

```
    TabView {
            Text("List")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    Text("List")
                }
            Text("Add") // I would like this view to be presented modally
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
                    Text("Add")
                }
        }
```

I am looking for native way to do it using `TabView` in `SwiftUI`.
I know I can write my own TabBar, but I would like to see if anyone has idea how to do it using build in `TabView`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`TabView` provides an optional parameter named `selection`, which lets you define a binding to a variable that holds the currently-selected tab. You use some type to represent a view, provide `TabView` with a binding to that type, then tag each tab's view with a value of that type. You can use `Int`s if you want, but since I prefer a bit more explicitness, I used an enum instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Tab {
        case list, add
    }

    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .list

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            VStack {
                Text("List")
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedTab = .add
                }, label: {
                    Text("Switch to Add tab")
                })
            }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    Text("List")
                }
                .tag(Tab.list)
            Text("Add") // I would like this view to be presented modally
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
                    Text("Add")
                }
                .tag(Tab.add)
        }
    }
}
```